# Table Transfer only one side in ANT DESIGN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I tried to table transfer one side transfer for products table and cart. I want the products selected from the products table to be transferred to the basket, but after the transfer, the selected product is deleted from the products table. If selected from the same product several times, It should be the group the same products in the basket.

Left Table is products table.

Right Table is cart table.

Problem is;

1. The selected product is deleted from the products table.
2. It is not grouped if more than one product is selected. (on cart)

[Code SandBox for example Table Transfer Ant Design](https://codesandbox.io/s/o55kn)

Answer (score 0):

I think you chose the wrong component. The Transfer is a non-cumulative component between two lists. The best option is to use two tables because you only need to push the elements on the right side, it is not necessary to delete the right element.